# WPF convert groustyle to style - how

Tags: xaml, listview, resourcedictionary

I have this XAML:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ContentPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,5,10,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                 Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent" />
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:AlignableWrapPanel HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="90" AllowDrop="True">
                    <Image Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Source="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>
                    <Label Width="90" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </controls:AlignableWrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And i want to be able to place it in a resourcedirectory file, so that i can reuse it for other classes, but i have no idea on how to convert the xaml to contain the styletag i need..

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Since the GroupStyle property exposes a collection, it's pretty complex to manage with just XAML. However, if you accept to apply only one style at once, here is a workaround in order to reuse the below code.

Basically create a class which derives from DependencyObject, the define an attached DP which will manage the insertion/removal of your GroupStyle against the ListView property.

```
public class ListViewHelpers : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "GroupStyle",
        typeof(GroupStyle),
        typeof(ListViewHelpers),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            null,
            GroupStyleChanged
            ));


    public GroupStyle GetGroupStyle(ListView target)
    {
        return (GroupStyle)GetValue(GroupStyleProperty);
    }


    public void SetGroupStyle(ListView target, GroupStyle value)
    {
        SetValue(GroupStyleProperty, value);
    }


    private static void GroupStyleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var lv = (ListView)sender;
        GroupStyle gs;

        gs = args.OldValue as GroupStyle;
        if (gs != null)
        {
            lv.GroupStyle.Remove(gs);
        }

        gs = args.NewValue as GroupStyle;
        if (gs != null)
        {
            lv.GroupStyle.Add(gs);
        }
    }
}
```

Afterward, you should declare somewhere the desired GroupStyle:

```
<GroupStyle x:Key="myGroupStyle">
  ...
</GroupStyle>
```

Then, in your XAML-declaration of the ListView, you can write as follow

```
<ListView myNS:ListViewHelpers.GroupStyle="{StaticResource myGroupStyle}">
  ...
</ListView>
```

---

Here follows the original answer, which is wrong, but kept as trace.

Two ways.

The first way is declaring the GroupStyle itself

```
<GroupStyle x:Key="myGroupStyle">
  ...
</GroupStyle>
```

then refer it as:

```
<ListView GroupStyle="{StaticResource myGroupStyle}">
  ...
</ListView>
```

The second way is styling the entire ListView, which is the best solution, IMHO:

```
<Style x:Key="myListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
  <Setter Property="GroupStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
      <GroupStyle>
        ...
      </GroupStyle>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Cheers

Comment: it won't let me set the groupstyle:
The property setter GroupStyle cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor.

Comment: You are right, my mistake because the accessor is a collection.

I think that the simplest way is to set is in the background code: define the GroupStyle as resource as above, the locate it using FindResource, for instance. Then, use the Add method of the GroupStyle property of the ListView to apply what you need.

Comment: ah cool.. can i make kinda my own control then, so that i can reuse it?